Post parameters and body data along with post request in truclient script
I have a post request need to send request from truclient script in loadrunner
Could you please let me know how  to pass parameters and body data along with post request
Pls find the post request
Https://api.dev.test.com/auth/token
Post data
Grant_type=user&id=testuser
Thanks
Post request along with body parameters in Trueclient

You are using the wrong virtual user type for the client architecture.  You would not use Truclient to excercise an HTTP based API directly.  You would use an HTTP or Web services virtual user as appropriate.   Truclient is for thick JavaScript framework web clients where you are representing a full browser execution model.
